# bootstrap multipage table didnt work full with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this bootstrap `multipage` table with search field. the button "bearbeiten" calling a modal (dialog) by Ajax Code by class (view_data) its working super just in page (1)...  when I move to another result by 'next' or when I search for something it doesn't working anymore

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
              $('.view_data').click(function(){ 
                   var em_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
                   $.ajax({  
                        url:"tbl_select.php",  
                        method:"post",  
                        data:{em_id:em_id},  
                        success:function(data){  
                             $('#ansp_detail').html(data);  
                             $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
                        }  
                   });  
              });  
         });
```

Comment: when you load new page any class/link is changed?

Comment: Use on() method for click event. check this link https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/

Comment: Thanks that's working super.

Comment: also you can use the https://datatables.net/ !